# The name 'img' does not exist in the current context

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to make a bottum image in my project but it is not correct, the error in my img

I'm doing the following

```
void tapImage_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //action
    }

    public AboutPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var tapImage = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapImage.Tapped += tapImage_Tapped;
        img.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapImage);
    }
```

In my xaml

```
        <cv:CarouselView x:Name="MAinCarousel" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="250">
        <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="img"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="Icon.png" Scale="1.0" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="250">
            </Grid> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </cv:CarouselView>
```

error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlS0V.png)

Comment: The variable `img` is not accessible from the `AboutPage` method.  It should either be a class variable, or get passed in as a parameter to the method.  The error means that variable is out of scope.

Comment: And how to fix it to work this way?

Comment: Like I said, the variable is out of scope, or, it doesn't exist. Maybe you can check to make sure `img` exists, and, if it does, pass it into the `AboutPage` method.  

Can you show the code where `img` is created?

Comment: <Image x:Name="img" 
In this line, the code above shows

Comment: if your source has 10 elements, then the template will create 10 copies of itself.  The name "img" is therefore ambiguous - there is no way to determine which copy of the template it refers to.  You can use gestures and command binding to attach a behavior to the template to make it open a page.

Comment: This is the problem I can not do this, do you have any examples that I can join my command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're declaring img inside of a DataTemplate. The views inside of the DataTemplate are not available or even created until you assign a source that resolves to the corresponding view.

Comment: How can i make for my img font to be viewed. How to do this inside my xaml?

Comment: You should add more information about what you're trying to achieve when this tap occurs. That will help get a better answer.

Comment: What I want and create a button image, I want to trigger an image by opening a page

Comment: Try adding your TapGestureRecognizer to your Image in the xaml itself.